# Swift картинки по ссылке

Tags: xcode, swift, изображения

Использую такой способ для получения картинки из ссылки

```
let url = URL(string:"http://apollo2.dl.playstation.net/cdn/EP0006/CUSA05359_00/upBsOb7yN9NwH87wQlhlA1x3CMlMk6iT.png")
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
    {
        ima.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }
```

Но картинки не видит вообще, из интернета беру любую другую - отображает, а эту нет, кто знает почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, случайно подумал, "а что если" и в итоге так и вышло, нужно просто *http* на **https** поменять было, почему то по *http* не хочет